# most recent row in a union query

Tags: sql

I have the following scenario
3 tables A.customers, B. invoices C. payments.

I want to union the invoices and payments by customer and take only tha most recent row (invoice or payment) to fetch the balance of each customer.
I have writen the following query but I get dizzy, confused and I need help

```
select *
FROM mainTable inner join

    (select max(dDate) as maxDate FROM
    (SELECT companies_1.id, 
            companies_1.eponymia, 
            invoices.datePublished AS dDate, 
            invoices.new_balance
     FROM    companies AS companies_1 
         INNER JOIN  invoices ON companies_1.id = invoices.pelaths_id
   UNION
     SELECT companies.id, 
            companies.eponymia, 
            payments.payDate AS dDate, 
            payments.new_balance
     FROM   payments 
         INNER JOIN  companies AS companies ON payments.pelaths_id = companies.id
) 
       AS mainTable
    GROUP by eponymia ) AS M ON maintable.dDate=m.dDate
```

This gives me error: the table [mainTable] does not exist.

How can I solve my problem?

Thank you

Comment: Step 1 - make the horizontal scroll bar go away so people can read your query.

Comment: First of all, this is one of those times where formatting can help you identify a problem, you should try writing a query in a more clear way. Secondly, I don't see a `[main table]` anywhere in that query, are you **sure** that that's the exact error and query?. Lastly, `m.date` doesn't exists, I only see `m.maxDate`; please try to use the same query you are using and error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to a table from an inner subquery outside that subquery.  The scoping is all off.

In most databases, you can just use window/analytic functions.  Here is a simpler approach:

```
select *
FROM (select maintable.*,
             row_number() over (partition by eponymia order by ddate desc) as seqnum 
      from (SELECT companies_1.id, companies_1.eponymia, invoices.datePublished AS dDate, invoices.new_balance
            FROM companies AS companies_1 INNER JOIN
                 invoices 
                 ON companies_1.id = invoices.pelaths_id
            UNION
            SELECT companies.id, companies.eponymia, payments.payDate AS dDate, payments.new_balance
            FROM payments INNER JOIN
                 companies AS companies
            ON payments.pelaths_id = companies.id
           ) mainTable
     ) M
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Actually, in op's case, the first table of the `JOIN` is `maintable`, so s/he shouldn't be getting that error

Comment: @Lamak . . . Think about the query.  It doesn't make sense if there is a table named `maintable`.  The OP is trying to use a subquery as a CTE -- which is another possible solution, but all databases (to my knowledge) that support CTEs also support `row_number()`.

Comment: Yeah. I was just trying to clarify the real issue op is facing. S/he says the error shows `[main table]`, with a space, which isn't in the query. I posted a comment also showing that s/he's using a column from the derived table that doesn't exist, so s/he should be getting another error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Actually this query must be run in a sql server CE which is not support row_number. That's why I get stucked